# fitting curve splitting in intervals based on x-value

Tags: python, pandas, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I want to fit some experimental data to a power curve of the form `Y = c1*Re^c2` where I have some experimental points of `Re` and `Y`.

I want to do this fitting in intervals. Thus, I want to find (for example) 3 curves (so 3 different sets of coefficient `C1` and `C2`) fitting `Y` to Re depending on the value of `Re`.

Right now, I am doing this manually, but this is very inconvenient, long and "dirty". Especially considering that, if I want the number of intervals to be arbitrary, it becomes super long to code (imagine dividing the span of `Re` into 10 or more intervals).

How can I make this smarter and shorter?

Here is the current code (I am using pandas to store the data, but maybe you have better suggestions here). In the code, I find the three sets of coefficients for intervals of `Re` between 0 and 150, between 150 and 1200 and for `Re > 1200`.

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import pandas as pd

def fitting_function(X, C1, C2):
    Re = X
    Y = C1*(Re**C2)
    return Y

df_fit = pd.DataFrame()

#my experimental data:
Re =[8,39,65,117,196,299,331,480,504,554,771,831,957,1180,1181,1472,1515,1558,1571,1709,1863,1931,2010,2127,2222]
Y = [435263,85974,52075,28727,18407,13949,13090,10285,9963,9365,8368,8243,8007,7684,7683,7352,7300,7269,7257,7136,7014,6955,6903,6831,6766]

df_fit["Re"] = Re
df_fit["Y"] = Y

Re_intervals = [150,1200]
df_fit_1 = df_fit[df_fit["Re"]<=Re_intervals[0]]
df_fit_2 = df_fit[df_fit["Re"]<=Re_intervals[1]][df_fit["Re"]>Re_intervals[0]]
df_fit_3 = df_fit[df_fit["Re"]>Re_intervals[1]]

df_fit_list = [df_fit_1, df_fit_2, df_fit_3]

dict_Coeff = {"C1":[], "C2":[]}

for df_ in df_fit_list:
    X_fitting = df_["Re"]
    Y_fitting = df_["Y"]
    C, pcov = curve_fit(fitting_function, X_fitting, Y_fitting)
    dict_Coeff_Nu["C1"].append(C_Nu[0])
    dict_Coeff_Nu["C2"].append(C_Nu[1])    
    
print("Coefficients Nu ", dict_Coeff_Nu)
```

I am using Python, but this is more of a logic/algorithm question.

Comment: What about this are you looking to automate? Without knowing anything about the data I wouldn't know how to split it up for multiple fits. It's also not clear why you're splitting it in the first place, especially considering you don't have any restriction on the end points to ensure the fits are continuous.

Comment: This is just an example, but I will be fitting based on Re values. I wanna split the entire Re range into intervals (in the example the intervals are 0-150/150-1200/1200-). In this case then I would need three separate fit functions as outcome. As per the continuity question, you are right but I already thought about replacing then the interval bounds with the intersection points of the three curves

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `pd.cut` to bin your data according to `Re` then pass your binned dataframe to a function that will return to you the list of dataframes you are looking for:
Here is a cleaner version of your code that tackles the repetitive issue you have:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import pandas as pd

def fitting_function(X, C1, C2):
    Re = X
    Y = C1*(Re**C2)
    return Y

#my experimental data:
Re =[8,39,65,117,196,299,331,480,504,554,771,831,957,1180,1181,1472,1515,1558,1571,1709,1863,1931,2010,2127,2222]
Y = [435263,85974,52075,28727,18407,13949,13090,10285,9963,9365,8368,8243,8007,7684,7683,7352,7300,7269,7257,7136,7014,6955,6903,6831,6766]

df_fit = pd.DataFrame({'Re': Re, 'Y': Y})

#### REPLACE THIS PART:
# Re_intervals = [150,1200]
# df_fit_1 = df_fit[df_fit["Re"]<=Re_intervals[0]]
# df_fit_2 = df_fit[df_fit["Re"]<=Re_intervals[1]][df_fit["Re"]>Re_intervals[0]]
# df_fit_3 = df_fit[df_fit["Re"]>Re_intervals[1]]

# df_fit_list = [df_fit_1, df_fit_2, df_fit_3]

#### REPLACE YOUT CODE WITH THIS PART:
def create_dfs_list(df, labels):
    list_df = []
    for label in labels:
        df_bin = df[df['Bin'] == label]
        list_df.append(df_bin)
    return list_df

labels = [1, 2, 3]

df_fit_list = (
    df_fit
    .assign(
        Bin = lambda df_: pd.cut(df_["Re"], bins=[0, 150, 1200, float('inf')], labels=labels)
    )
    .pipe(create_dfs_list, labels)
)

# ---------------------------------------------

# THE REST OF YOUR CODE

# dict_Coeff = {"C1":[], "C2":[]}

# for df_ in df_fit_list:
#     X_fitting = df_["Re"]
#     Y_fitting = df_["Y"]
#     C, pcov = curve_fit(fitting_function, X_fitting, Y_fitting)
#     dict_Coeff_Nu["C1"].append(C_Nu[0])
#     dict_Coeff_Nu["C2"].append(C_Nu[1])    
    
# print("Coefficients Nu ", dict_Coeff_Nu)
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Great! this works perfectly to create my df in an automated manner!